# Can an entrypoint be used in setup.py for running uvicorn programmatically?

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

The [uvicorn documentation on running programmatically](https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-programmatically) suggesting:

> you should put uvicorn.run into if **name** == '**main**' clause in the main module

Example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("service:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

Is there a way to start the server using a `setup.py` entrypoint:

Tried:

```
'entry_points': {
    'console_scripts': [
        'my_service=my_service.service:main',
    ],
},
```

then set:

```
def main():
    uvicorn.run("my_service.service:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

However, now it is not running as a top level script.

Can it be done to satisfy both the entrypoint as well as running as uvicorn suggests?